# C# - Saving values in Listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, save, text-files, savefiledialog

I have the following code:

```
SaveFileDialog saveGC1File = new SaveFileDialog();

private void GCSavePlacementOneButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Initialize the SaveFileDialog to specify the .txt extension for the file.
    saveGC1File.DefaultExt = "*.txt";
    saveGC1File.Filter = ".txt Files|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    saveGC1File.RestoreDirectory = true;

    try
    {
        string placementOneSave = placementOneListBox.Items.ToString();

        // Save the contents of the formattedTextRichTextBox into the file.
        if (saveGC1File.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && saveGC1File.FileName.Length > 0)
            placementOneSave.SaveFile(saveGC1File.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

        // Throws a FileNotFoundException otherwise.
        else
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }

    // Catches an exception if the file was not saved.
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was not a specified file path.", "Path Not Found Error",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
}
```

However, using Visual Studio 2010, the line  in the "if" loop that states:

```
"placementOneSave.SaveFile(saveGC1File.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);"
```

Has a **red** line under the "SaveFile".. I have used this code to save a file before and am unsure why it will not work for a ListBox.

---

***QUESTIONS***

- How can I save a ListBox in a similar way to a RichTextBox?
- Any way to edit this code to make it have the user choose where the ListBox will be saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListBox does not provide a method to save all its items to a file.  The code snippet showing how this can be done is available here:

[C# code to save text from listbox to a text file -- SOLVED--](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/275461-C-code-to-save-text-from-listbox-to-a-text-file-SOLVED)